# Batch for loop to rename with timestamp and move files from one folder to another one

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to move zip files from one folder to another one with batch. I want to understand how to complete my piece of code in order to move zip files from one folder to another one renaming files, adding to the name of the file the timestamp.

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b  \\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\*.zip ^| find /c /v ""') do (

)
EXIT
```

EDIT

In python I would have written something like this:

```
Location = '\\\\XXXX\\XXX\\XXX\\XXX\\XXX\\'
checklist2 = glob.glob(Location + '*.zip')

for filename2 in checklist2:
    NewName = filename2.replace(Location, '')
    NewName = NewName.replace('.ZIP', '')
    shutil.move(filename2, Location + 'Archive\\ZIP Archive\\' + NewName + '_' + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip')
```

Comment: You are not giving enough detail. Show example files you use as input and expected output.

Comment: i am using all zip files present inside the folder considered

Comment: the expected output is to move zip file from one folder to archive folder

Comment: given that expected output, what is wrong with `move *.zip destinationfolder`

Comment: Well, actually the for loop in the batch is working because i am using it.

Comment: are you talking about the python script?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard The OP wants to rename the file to include its timestamp.

Comment: @avery_larry yeah, I think you are missing the point. The question is off topic (especially how it was at the time I asked the question). Questions need to be complete and it was/is not. The comment then purely stated that OP wants to move files from one dir to another. We try and force people to do something the write questions complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you this helps you:

```
for %%a in (*) do echo %%~na-%%~ta%%~xa
```

`%%~na` is the name of the file.
`%%~ta` is the timestamp of the file.
`%%~xa` is the file extension.

Comment: Nope. How do you plan on renaming files like this? have you tested it yet?

Comment: I was just trying to push the OP in the right direction -- I was not trying to write the entire code.  If the OP takes this, tries to write their own code and has more problems then they can further edit their question.  I suppose I think this "answer" strikes a balance with still trying to be helpful despite the poor and/or off topic question.

Comment: That is the problem. Off topic questions lead to off topic and incorrect answers, leading to more problems and confusing more and more people. Minimal, complete and verifiable questions are expected and ditto for answers. We all want to help people, but we spend our time for free to do so, if a user asks an unclear question we spend more time trying to find out more, same with answers.